# How to write JSON with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have this currencies.json file:

```
{
  "USD": {
        "ValueUSD": 325.33,
        "ValueEUR": 344.55,
        "PreviousValueUSD": 324.55,
        "PreviousValueEUR": 354.55,
  },
  "EUR": {
        "ValueUSD": 325.33,
        "ValueEUR": 344.55,
        "PreviousValueUSD": 324.55,
        "PreviousValueEUR": 354.55,
  }
}
```

I need to parse it into "#content" using jQuery. Can someone help me with a code to do this? I think jSONP is needed because the feed is from another server.

Example for output needed:

```
<div class="currency">USD, 325.33, 344.55, 324.55, 354.55</div>
<div class="currency">EUR, 325.33, 344.55, 324.55, 354.55</div>
```

Comment: Does the server offer the content as JSONP? Before you worry about manipulating the content, you need to make sure you can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// you will get from server
var obj = $.parseJSON(data); // data contains the string

for (var key in obj) {
  $('<div class="currency" />')
    .html(key + ', ' + $.map(obj[key], function(val) { return val; })
    .join(', ')).appendTo('body');
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/igubor/2/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

- `$.parseJSON` is used to parse the string into the object.
- Then for each currency inside object use `.map()` to map the values.
- Join the values into a string separated by `,`, append into the `div` and a currency name.
- Resulting `div` append to the body.

**Update** (see comments):

If you want to retrieve this data cross-domain use:

```
$.getJSON('www.domain.com/currencies.json?callback=?', function(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    $('<div class="currency" />')
    .html(key + ', ' + $.map(data[key], function(val) { return val; })
    .join(', ')).appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

Comment: What do I have to add if I have the data on a different server? Because the file will be located at: www.domain.com/currencies.json

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help (the data parsed from your JSON above is held in the `data` variable):

```
var $body = $("body"),
    key,
    $div,
    txt,
    innerKey;

for (key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $div= $("<div></div").addClass("currency");
        txt = [key, ", "];
        for (innerKey in data[key]) {
            if (data[key].hasOwnProperty(innerKey)) {
                txt.push(data[key][innerKey]);
                txt.push(", ");
            }
        }

        // Remove the trailing comma
        txt.pop(); 

        // Set the HTML content of the div and then add to the body
        $div.html(txt.join("")).appendTo($body);
    }
}
```

Here's a [working example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/XZvTX/).

Comment: What do I have to add if I have the data on a different server? Because the file will be located at: www.domain.com/currencies.json

Comment: Just use jQuery's [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to retrieve your data. The link I've provided gives details on how to use with JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

well you can access things like:

data.USD.ValueUSD will get you 325.33 so you can do something liek this. pass your data object that you get from your ajax call in ur success func to call this function:

```
function populateContent(data){

     var $currencyDiv = $('<div class="currency"></div>'),
     $currencyDiv2 = $currencyDiv.clone();

     $currencyDiv.html("USD, "+data.USD.ValueUSD + ", " + data.USD.ValueEUR + ", " + data.USD.PreviousValueUSD + ", " + data.USD.PreviousValueEUR);

     //do the same for currencydiv2
     //append your new content divs wherever you want

     $('body').append($currencyDiv);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more puristic approach that could also help you understand how to iterate through objects (and is browser native and therefore not relying on jQuery)

```
for(var data in #YOUR_JSON_DATA# ){ // iterate through the JSON nodes
  var tmp = data; // store the current node in temporary variable
  for(var val in json[data]){ // iterate through the current nodes' children
    tmp += ", " + json[data][val]; // this is how you access multidimensional objects. format your output as you like
  }
  alert(tmp); // see the output. here you could use jquery to write this into your page.
}
```